# How to use FIXT11 function in quickFix/n package

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

I have a question of using FIXT1.1 xml.

Indeed, I have successfully established the connection by using the transport dictionary (FIXT11.xml) and app dictionary (FIX50SP2.xml) ; However, I would like to do the following action manually:

1. Resend Request
2. SequenceReset

I found these two messages available in the transport dictionary:

```
<fix type='FIXT' major='1' minor='1' servicepack='0'>
...
<message msgcat='admin' msgtype='2' name='ResendRequest'>
  <field name='BeginSeqNo' required='Y'/>
  <field name='EndSeqNo' required='Y'/>
</message>
<message msgcat='admin' msgtype='4' name='SequenceReset'>
  <field name='GapFillFlag' required='N'/>
  <field name='NewSeqNo' required='Y'/>
</message>
```

but I cannot create this message class manually as I used to in FIX44. I've looked through the names spaces in QuickFix.dll but there is no such object know as QuickFix.FIXT11 in the quickfix/n package

[Create message directly using QuickFix/n FIX44 object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQqnh.png)

[QuickFix.FIXT11 missing in quickfix/n package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsT44.png)

Do you have any recommendation what should I do?